# How the type length restriction works for ASN.1 definition

Tags: asn.1

A question about the ASN.1 encoding mechanism for the primitive types.
For example, I have the following type definition in test.asn1:

NodeID ::= IA5String (SIZE(1..20))

Here the NodeId can with maximum string length 20.
My question was: what if the value assigned to NodeID exceeds the maximum length 20 ?
Can it pass the encode function (use BER) ?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BER doesn't take constraints into account.  You could certainly have a BER encoding for an invalid NodeID, where the value violates the size constraint.  Of course, your tools may prevent you from doing this, but from the perspective of ASN.1, it would be possible.

Comment: Strange, as I am using BER but it seems that my system uses constraints for OCTET STRING for example, but not for IA5STRING and INTEGER. Any reference for "BER doesn't take constraints into account"?

Comment: @maiky You can look at X.690 for a full description of BER encoding.  When BER encodes values, the encoding does not vary based on the existence of constraints; that is in contrast to PER where there are cases where it is actually impossible to encode certain invalid values.  Again, this doesn't make the invalid value valid, it just means that someone could create BER data that contains invalid values.

Comment: @maiky Actually, they spell it out in X.690 (2015) 8.1.1.4: "Encodings specified in this Recommendation | International Standard are not affected by either the ASN.1 subtype notation or the ASN.1 type extensibility notation.  NOTE – This means that all constraint notation is ignored when determining encodings, and all extensibility markers in CHOICE, SEQUENCE and SET are ignored, with the extensions treated as if they were in the extension root of the type."